# Keycloak 22.0.1: User login unauthorized

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to login a user after being created but i get the 401 Unauthorized response.

```
def login_to_keycloak(username, password):
    auth_data = {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }
    r = requests.post(KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS + "/admin/realms/" + KEYCLOAK_REALM + '/protocol/openid-connect/token', data=auth_data)
    print_result(r)
    return r
```

Before the login, i receive the access token and create the user successfully:

```
def get_keycloak_admin_token():
    payload = {
        'client_id': KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
    r = requests.post(KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS+'/realms/'+KEYCLOAK_REALM+'/protocol/openid-connect/token', data=payload)
    print_result(r)
    return r


def create_keycloak_user(token, name, email, password):
    user_data = {
        'username': name,
        'email': email,
        'enabled': True,
        'emailVerified': True,
        'credentials': [{
            'type': 'password',
            'value': password,
            'temporary': False
        }]
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    r = requests.post(KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS + "/admin/realms/"+KEYCLOAK_REALM+"/users", json=user_data, headers=headers)
    print_result(r)
    return r
```

I also granted the direct access for my client:

[image]

I even tried to add the authorization header to the login request but i get 404 response:

```
headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```

The client has the user managment roles too.

[image]
Is there another config I need to set in the Keycloak Admin UI?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the solution, I guess it can be a bug.

I solved my issue using an earlier version (Keycloak 21.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the 22.0.1 version. I made it work by using the admin-cli client to create the user and then my custom client to authenticate the user:

```
def get_keycloak_admin_token():
    payload = {
        'client_id': 'admin-cli',
        'client_secret': KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_CLI_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    r = requests.post(KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS+'/realms/'+KEYCLOAK_REALM+'/protocol/openid-connect/token', data=payload, headers=headers)
    print_result(r)
    return r


def create_keycloak_user(token, name, email, password):
    user_data = {
        'username': name,
        'email': email,
        'enabled': True,
        'emailVerified': True,
        'credentials': [{
            'type': 'password',
            'value': password,
            'temporary': False
        }]
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    r = requests.post(KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS + "/admin/realms/"+KEYCLOAK_REALM+"/users", json=user_data, headers=headers)
    print_result(r)
    return r


def login_to_keycloak(username, password):
    auth_data = {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    r = requests.post(KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS + "/realms/" + KEYCLOAK_REALM + '/protocol/openid-connect/token', data=auth_data, headers=headers)
    print_result(r)
    return r
```